# WordPress - how to overcome category and page permalink clashes

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

In WordPress, I have a category and subcategory:

```
Donkey (slug=donkey-category)
   Reports (slug=reports - parent category is donkey-category)
```

I also have a page:

```
Donkey (slug=donkey, categorised as donkey-category)
```

And I have a series of posts:

```
My post name 1 (categorised a donkey-category and reports)
My post name 2 (categorised a donkey-category and reports)
etc.
```

I want the page to have the permalink /donkey

I want the category index page to have the permalink /donkey/reports

I want each of the posts to have the permalink /donkey/reports/my-post-name-1, etc.

But because the page is called "Donkey" and the parent categories is called "Donkey" I am having to give one of them a different slug and that either compromises the permalink for the page or for the category and posts.

I have configured a Permalink custom structure: /%category%/%postname%/

And I have the "Remove Category URL" plugin (to avoid the /category/donkey-category verbosity)

Comment: Just a quick thought: It might work if you give indeed the `Donkey` category another name internally and use `rewrite rules`, so that `/ABC/reports` points to `/ABC-category/reports`. How should WordPress otherwise know what you mean?

Comment: Thanks - yes that's an option.  I suppose I was hoping I could give the page and the category the same slug but specify somehow that the page trumps the category (so /donkey shows the page but where /donkey/... is part of a more complete url, it's referring to the category.)  I suspect this is dreamland (though anything's possible with a plugin!)

Comment: You should try and avoid such design conflicts in the first place. If you can't, then using rewrite is ok for problems like this. Plugins like `WPS Hide Login` do the same to "rename" the `/wp-admin` URL.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you want, should `/donkey/reports` display the posts from the category `reports` or the category `donkey-category`? And the `donkey-category` posts should be displayed for `/donkey url`? If it's the case why you have a `donkey` page?

Comment: @vard `/donkey` should show the donkey page; `/donkey/reports` should show posts from the category `reports`; `/donkey/reports/my-post-name-1` should show that post.